# Updating Ubuntu, Unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, software-center, dpkg, dependencies

When trying to open Ubuntu Software center getting this:

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are
missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software
packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

When trying to execute: `sudo apt-get -f install` getting this:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 leap : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 7.7.1) or
                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-precise (>= 7.7.1) but it is not installable or
                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal (>= 7.7.1) but it is not installed or
                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring (>= 7.7.1) but it is not installed or
                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy (>= 7.7.1) but it is not installed or
                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty (>= 7.7.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` as it said?

Comment: it's the answer, when I try to do it

Answer (score 0):

#### Good Luck!

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. `sudo apt-get -f install`
3. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
4. `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all leap`